# Can jQuery UI Dialog instance be saved and reopened?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am wondering if whether a jQuery UI Dialog instance can be saved to a file/database in such a fashion that it can be restored to it's original state later?

I mean something like this:

```
var save_instance = jQuery.stringify(instance); /* instance variable here refers to a Dialog's instance that I am trying to save */
```

And then whenever I need to restore it:

```
jQuery(JSON.parse(save_instance)).dialog();
```

The latter gives me an error and doesn't work as I was hoping to.

Is this something which is just not possible? Or is it something I am doing wrong?